# Linux Bash Print largest number in column from monthly rotated log file

Tags: shell, awk

I have monthly rotated log files which looks like the output below. The files are names `transc-2301.log` (transc-YMM). There is a file for each month of the year. I need a simple bash command to find the file of the current month, and display the largest number (max) of column 3. In the example below, the output should be `87`

```
01/02/23 10:45  19      26
01/02/23 11:45  19      45
01/02/23 12:45  19      36
01/02/23 13:45  22      64
01/02/23 14:45  19      72
01/02/23 15:45  19      54
01/02/23 16:45  19      80
01/02/23 17:45  17      36
01/03/23 10:45  18      24
01/03/23 11:45  19      26
01/03/23 12:45  19      48
01/03/23 13:45  20      87
01/03/23 14:45  20      29
01/03/23 15:45  18      26
```

Comment: "I need a simple bash command" - ok, start with minimal coding effort and post it

Comment: Yeah i found `awk '{if ($4 > max) max=$4}END{print max}' transc-2301.log` to be working, but need to get ` date +"%y%m"` in the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your filenames are sortable you can easily pick the file of the current month as being the last one in a sortable sequence. Than a quick awk returns the result.

```
for file in transc_*.log; do :; done
awk '($3>m){m=$3}END{print m}' "$file"
```

alternatively you can let awk do the heavy lifting on the filename

```
awk 'BEGIN{ARGV[1]=ARGV[ARGC-1];ARGC=2}($3>m){m=$3}END{print m}' transc_*.log
```

or if you don't like the glob-expansion trick:

```
awk '($3>m){m=$3}END{print m}' "transc_$(date "+%y%m").log"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `transc-2301.log` content be

```
01/02/23 10:45  19      26
01/02/23 11:45  19      45
01/02/23 12:45  19      36
01/02/23 13:45  22      64
01/02/23 14:45  19      72
01/02/23 15:45  19      54
01/02/23 16:45  19      80
01/02/23 17:45  17      36
01/03/23 10:45  18      24
01/03/23 11:45  19      26
01/03/23 12:45  19      48
01/03/23 13:45  20      87
01/03/23 14:45  20      29
01/03/23 15:45  18      26
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{m=-1;FS="[[:space:]]{2,}";logname=strftime("transc-%y%m.log")}FILENAME==logname{m=$3>m?$3:m}END{print m}' transc*.log
```

gives output (as of 18 Jan 2023)

```
87
```

**Warning**: I assume your file use as separator two-or-more whitespace characters, if this does not hold adjust `FS` accordingly. **Warning**: set `m` to value which is lower than lowest value which might appear in column of interest. Explanation: I use [`strftime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) function to detect what file should be processed and ram all `transc*.log` files but action is only taken for selected file, action is: set `m` to `$3` if it is higher than current `m` otherwise keep `m` value. After processing files, in `END`, I `print` value of `m`.

*(tested ub GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: This processes every line of all files, even if you don't need to process the file.

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> mawk '_<(__ = +$NF) { _=__ } END { print +_ }'
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> gawk 'END { print +_ } (_=_<(__=+$NF) ?__:_)<_'
> ```

```
87
```

Comment: Very obscure with the `__` and `_`

Comment: @kvantour : because calling them `i` and `j` is any better ?

Comment: it is just more readable and people are more inclined to understand it. variables which are not alphanumeric could be interpreted as special variables (eg `_` in bash). readers could make a similar assumption in this case. If your code is more readable, your answers might get more upvotes. I don't say it is wrong, I just say that readers need more time to interpret it as they are not used to reading code with mainly non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @kvantour : which is why it's important for someone to use actual examples, like solutions to questions posted, as means to showcase why, unlike `bash` or `perl`, `$_ | _` **aren't special** ***at all*** in `awk`, and hopefully dispel this widely held misconception….

Comment: @kvantour : …… Another advantage of `_<(__=+$NF)` is that one doesn't even need to assign a very low default value to `_`, since `_` defaults to an empty string, which means 1st row's data value, assume it has ANY value, will always be `"greater than"` an empty string, so that notation alone takes care of both the normal comparisons as well as the initialization default case.

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. In awk, un-initialized variables are of type `strnum` (both string and numeric). Fields that can represent a number are also of `strnum` type. Any comparison between two `strnum` will be of numeric and un-initialized variables will than have the number zero. If you search for a max value, but all your numbers are negative, this would fail.

Comment: @kvantour : that's true …. except that we aren't dealing with negative inputs in this question.:::::::::::::  and ps : `will "then" have`